# WPF ListBox.ScrollIntoView works only it has focus

Tags: wpf

i  have wpf (FW 4.8) application. it's kind of video player. it has some buttons, menue, mediaElement and a listBox with subtitles.
subtitles are synchronized with vodeo (timer).
everything works ok untill the current subtitle is not in the visible area of the listbox.

to bring it to view i use SubtitlesListBox.ScrollIntoView(listBoxItem). but it works only if i set focus on it. like this:

```
IInputElement focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
listBoxItem.Focus();
SubtitlesListBox.ScrollIntoView(listBoxItem);
focusedElement?.Focus();
```

this makes it difficult to operate with other controls.
how can i do it correctly?
thank you